# Rock-paper-scissors game c++

Tags: c++

Rock-paper-scissors game c++ doesn't display the cout to tell who win the game, i dont know what wrong and why is the program doesn't show the cout. Please let me know whats wrong and how to fix it and why it happened and i think the cstdlib is doing nothing there.

> Objective: To score the rock-paper-scissors game. If the user enters
>   invalid input, your program should say so, otherwise it will output
>   one of the above results.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <cstdlib> 

using namespace std; 

int main() 
{ 
    string pone; 
    string ptwo; 
    string r; 
    string p; 
    string s; 

    cout << "Rock, Paper, Scissors Game\n"; 
    cout << "\nPlayer One, please enter your move: ('p' for Paper, 'r' for Rock, 's' for Scissor)";  

    cin >> pone; 

    cout << "\nPlayer Two, please enter your move: ('p' for Paper, 'r' for Rock, 's' for Scissor)"; 

    cin >> ptwo; 

    if (pone == ptwo) 
    { 
        cout <<"\nThere is a tie"<<endl; 
    } 

    if ( pone == r && ptwo == p) 
    { 
        cout << "\nPaper wraps rock, Player 1 win"; 
    } 
    else if (pone == r && ptwo == s) 
    { 
        cout << "\nRock smashes scissors, player 1 win"; 
    } 

    if (pone == p && ptwo == r) 
    { 
        cout <<"\nPaper wraps rock, player 1 win"; 
    } 
    else if ( pone == p && ptwo == s) 
    { 
        cout <<"\nScissors cut paper, player 2 win"; 
    } 

    if ( pone == r && ptwo == p) 
    { 
        cout << "\nPaper wraps rock, Player 1 win"; 
    } 
    else if (pone == r && ptwo == s) 
    { 
        cout << "\nRock smashes scissors, player 1 win"; 
    } 

    if (pone == p && ptwo == r) 
    { 
        cout <<"\nPaper wraps rock, player 1 win"; 
    } 
    else if ( pone == p && ptwo == s) 
    { 
        cout <<"\nScissors cut paper, player 2 win"; 
    } 

    if ( ptwo == s && pone == r) 
    { 
        cout <<"\nScissors cut paper, player 1 win"; 
    } 
    else if (ptwo == s && pone == p) 
    { 
        cout <<"\nRock smashes scissors, player 2 win "; 
    } 

    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Did you step through your program with a debugger?

Comment: Do you see other outputs such as `cout << "Rock, Paper, Scissors Game\n";`? Is the final result the only output which is missing?

Comment: Why didn't you put a check as to whether both inputs are valid, before jumping to deciding who wins?

Comment: Why didn't you initialize any of your string variables?

Comment: @DanielDaranas I think he's confusing the string literals "r", "p", and "s" with the strings r, p, and s. There is of course no need to initialize string variables if he's using cin to get the values for them.

To OP: there's no need for you to declare the string variables r, p, and s

Comment: how to make check point as to whether both inputs are valid and if not cout<< invalid input how to do this step

Answer (score 2):

Here's your problem:

```
if (pone == r && ptwo == p) 
{ 
    cout << "\nPaper wraps rock, Player 1 win"; 
} 
else if (pone == r && ptwo == s) 
{ 
    cout << "\nRock smashes scissors, player 1 win"; 
} 
//etc etc
```

put those "r", "p", and "s" in quotes like such:

```
if (pone == "r" && ptwo == "p")
//etc etc
```

and you should be good

Comment: how to make check point that check the user put the valid input and if not cout<< invalid input how to do this step

Comment: so right after your cin, you should do a check like

`if((pone != "r" && pone != "p" && pone !="s") || (ptwo != "r" && ptwo != "p" && ptwo !="s")){//error }`

Answer (score 1):

You should assign some values to r, p and s

Preferably

```
r = "r";
p = "p";
s = "s";
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is kinda late but...

Here is my program. I used your if elseif section of the code and found a problem with it.
 you repeat 2/3s of the code twice

****this part****

```
if ( pone == r && ptwo == p) 
    { 
        cout << "\nPaper wraps rock, Player 1 win"; 
    } 
    else if (pone == r && ptwo == s) 
    { 
        cout << "\nRock smashes scissors, player 1 win"; 
    }
```

**and this part**

```
if (pone == p && ptwo == r) 
{ 
    cout <<"\nPaper wraps rock, player 1 win"; 
} 
else if ( pone == p && ptwo == s) 
{ 
    cout <<"\nScissors cut paper, player 2 win"; 
}
```

Here is my version of the code, (its a full program ready to be run)
hope this helps :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int userChoice;     // To hold the user's choice
int computerChoice; // To hold the computer's choice
int choice;



//function prototypes
int getUserChoice(int);

int getComputerChoice();

void determineWinner(int,int);

void displayChoice (int userChoice, int computerChoice);




//*************************************************
//Function main
//*************************************************
int main()
{


    // Get the computer's choice.
    computerChoice = getComputerChoice();

    // Get the user's choice.
    userChoice = getUserChoice(choice);

    while (userChoice != 4)
    {
        //Displays selections
        displayChoice (userChoice,computerChoice);

        // Determine the winner.
        determineWinner(userChoice, computerChoice);

        // Get the computer's choice.
        computerChoice = getComputerChoice();

        // Get the user's choice.
        userChoice = getUserChoice(choice);
    }//end while

    return 0;
}
//end main






// The getUserChoice function displays a menu allowing
// the user to select rock, paper, or scissors. The
// function then returns 1 for rock (via the ROCK
// constant), or 2 for paper (via the PAPER constant),
// or 3 for scissors (via the SCISSORS constant).
int getUserChoice(int choice)
{
    cout<<"\n\nROCK PAPER SCISSORS!!!";
    cout<<"\n---------\n1) Rock\n2) Paper\n3) Scissors\n4) Quit\n\n";
    cout<<"Enter your choice:";
    cin>>choice;
    return choice;
}//end getUserChoice




// The getComputerChoice function returns the computer's
// game choice. It returns 1 for rock (via the ROCK
// constant), or 2 for paper (via the PAPER constant),
// or 3 for scissors (via the SCISSORS constant).
int getComputerChoice()
{
    int number;
    int seed = time(0);//gets system time
    srand(seed);//seed the random number

    number = 1 + rand() % 3;//generate random # 1-3
    return number;
}//end getComputerChoice






// The displayChoice function accepts an integer
// argument and displays rock, paper, or scissors.
void displayChoice(int userChoice, int computerChoice)
{

//displays what you&the comp selected 
    if(userChoice == 1)
    {
        cout<<"You selected: Rock\n";
    }//end if

    else if(userChoice == 2)
    {
        cout<<"You selected: Paper\n";
    }//end else if

    else if(userChoice == 3)
    {
        cout<<"You selected: Scissors\n";
    }//end else if #2


    if(computerChoice == 1)
    {
        cout<<"The computer selected: Rock\n";
    }//end if

    else if(computerChoice == 2)
    {
        cout<<"The computer selected: Paper\n";
    }//end else if

    else if(computerChoice == 3)
    {
        cout<<"The computer selected: Scissors\n";
    }//end else if #2

}






// The determineWinner function accepts the user's
// game choice and the computer's game choice as
// arguments and displays a message indicating
// the winner.
void determineWinner(int userChoice, int computerChoice)
{
//determines winner 
    if (userChoice == computerChoice) 
    { 
        cout <<"Tie. NO WINNER.\n\n"<<endl; 
    } 

    if ( userChoice == 1 && computerChoice == 2) 
    { 
        cout << "Paper wraps rock, COMPUTER WINS\n\n"; 
    } 
    else if (userChoice == 1 && computerChoice == 3) 
    { 
        cout << "Rock smashes scissors. YOU WON!\n\n"; 
    } 

    if (userChoice == 2 && computerChoice == 1) 
    { 
        cout <<"Paper wraps rock. YOU WON!\n\n"; 
    } 
    else if ( userChoice == 2 && computerChoice == 3) 
    { 
        cout <<"Scissors cut paper, COMPUTER WINS\n\n"; 
    } 

    if ( userChoice == 3 && computerChoice == 1) 
    { 
        cout <<"Scissors cut paper, COMPUTER WINS\n\n"; 
    } 
    else if (userChoice == 3 && computerChoice == 2) 
    { 
        cout <<"Rock smashes scissors. YOU WON!\n\n"; 
    }

}//end determindWinner




/*
Proof




ROCK PAPER SCISSORS!!!
---------
1) Rock
2) Paper
3) Scissors
4) Quit

Enter your choice:1
You selected: Rock
The computer selected: Paper
Paper wraps rock, COMPUTER WINS



ROCK PAPER SCISSORS!!!
---------
1) Rock
2) Paper
3) Scissors
4) Quit

Enter your choice:2
You selected: Paper
The computer selected: Paper
Tie. NO WINNER.




ROCK PAPER SCISSORS!!!
---------
1) Rock
2) Paper
3) Scissors
4) Quit

Enter your choice:3
You selected: Scissors
The computer selected: Paper
Rock smashes scissors. YOU WON!



ROCK PAPER SCISSORS!!!
---------
1) Rock
2) Paper
3) Scissors
4) Quit

Enter your choice:4
Press any key to continue . . .
*/
```